# Как спарсить значение массы из таблицы характеристик товара?

Tags: парсер, xpath

Есть такой отрывок кода:

```
<td class="param-head">
<dl>
<dt class="n-product-spec__name">
<span class="n-product-spec__name-inner">Диаметр мембранного бака</span>
</dt>
<dd class="n-product-spec__value">
<span class="n-product-spec__value-inner">229 мм</span>
</dd>
</dl>
</td>
<td class="param-head">
<dl>
<dt class="n-product-spec__name">
<span class="n-product-spec__name-inner">Масса</span>
</dt>
<dd class="n-product-spec__value">
<span class="n-product-spec__value-inner">14 кг</span>
</dd>
</dl>
</td>
```

Мне нужно именно значение массы: `14 кг`.

Не пойму, как написать путь в запросе парсинга *XPath,* в связи с тем что все классы повторяются для разных атрибутов, и применять порядковый номер тоже не вариант — в разных товарах масса под разным порядковым номером.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разбил на строчки для читаемости.

```
//dt[@class="n-product-spec__name" and span[@class="n-product-spec__name-inner" and .="Масса"]]
/following-sibling::dd[1][@class="n-product-spec__value"]
//span[@class="n-product-spec__value-inner"]/text()
```

1. Ищем dt со словом Масса
2. Берем первый следующий dd нужного класса
3. Выбираем значение span

Comment: Прошу прощения за безграмотность, и за то что сразу в исходных данных не предоставил всю полную информацию: по сложившимся обстоятельствам парсинг делаю в гугл таблице, и далеко не все видимо понимаю. В общем ошибку выдает в этой формуле: =IMPORTXML(A1;"//dt[@class="n-product-spec__name" and span[@class="n-product-spec__name-inner" and .="Масса"]]/following-sibling::dd[1][@class="n-product-spec__value"]//span[@class="n-product-spec__value-inner"]/text()")

Comment: A1=https://shop.ekodar.ru/product/409ab047834e11e880c70cc47aaa3885#

Comment: говорит, страница не найдена

Comment: Сорри, город Краснодар надо выбрать Просто если на сайте выбран город например Москва то тогда страница возвращает 404.

Comment: я выполнил в chrome, поменяв на "высоту", `$x('//dt[@class="n-product-spec__name" and span[@class="n-product-spec__name-inner" and .="Высота"]]/following-sibling::dd[1][@class="n-product-spec__value"]//span[@class="n-product-spec__value-inner"]/text()')` получил `1335 мм` два раза

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста где ошибка ибо не получается чет: =IMPORTXML("shop.ekodar.ru/product/9338dc5856d245f4bf1e3212d7dfe20e";//dt[@class="n-product-spec__name" and span[@class="n-product-spec__name-inner" and .="Высота"]]/following-sibling::dd[1][@class="n-product-spec__value"]//span[@class="n-product-spec__value-inner"]/text() ошибку выдает (https намеренно убрал в этом комментарии для отображения всей формулы)

Comment: с кавычками разберитесь - у вас одинаковые и вокруг xpath, и внутри

Comment: Спасибо, вроде разобрались